# Find most common values in relation to two columns

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have two columns: "Character" and "Type". I have multiple characters in a list, and each character can be one of five types. For example:

```
Character | Type
----------------
Ally      | A
Ally      | A
Betty     | B
Betty     | A
Ally      | A
Betty     | C
Betty     | C
Betty     | B
Ally      | C
```

I want to find the most common value in relation to *both* columns. So the output would be something like this:

```
Most Common Character Types:
Character | Type | #
---------------------
Ally      |  A   | 3
Betty     |  B   | 2
Betty     |  C   | 2
Ally      |  C   | 1
Betty     |  A   | 1
```

The thing is, I'm working with a lot more characters than just "Ally" and "Betty" (more than 100). The closest thing I can get to a combination ref table (using COUNTIFS) would be:

```
     | A | B | C | D | E |
--------------------------
Ally | 3 | 0 | 1 | 8 | 2 |
--------------------------
Betty| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 8 |
--------------------------
Carl | 5 | 5 | 0 | 7 | 6 |
--------------------------
Drew | 6 | 8 | 1 | 9 | 2 |
```

However, I've ran into a mindblock and I can't figure out how to extract that information and put it into a "Top 10 Most Common" chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put your data in A19:B28 like on the screenshot. Then the query below will give you what you want:

```
=query(A19:B28, "select A, B, count(A) group by A, B", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, so it was query? I am not familiar with query. This answer helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ttarchala's answer worked, but there were a few other things that the function didn't address. After some research, I figured them out. This information is to help other users having similar problems, especially those who are not familiar with QUERY, like me.

- **What if the columns are not directly side-by-side?**

Due to my negligence, I did not state this in my original post. However, it is easy to fix. Say instead of columns A and B, the columns were E and J. 
Instead of `=query(A19:B28, "select A, B, count(A) group by A, B", 1)`, you would simply put in `=query(E:J, "select E, J, count(E) group by E, J", 1)`. Essentially, you would specify the range and then tell the function which columns to focus on.

- **How can I order by descending count?**

The given function currently has no order. Add `Order by count(E) desc` so you would have `=query(E:J, "select E, J, count(E) group by E, J Order by count(E) desc", 1)`.

- **How can I limit the output to ten entries?**

Add `limit 10` to your function. Replace "10" with however many outputs you want.

- **The graph now works properly, but I see that the count column is labeled with "count Name". Can I change that?**

Yes. Add `label count(E) '#'` to your function with **#** being whatever you would like the column to be called.